# Python argv IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, argv

I want to input file drag-drop on the python output is a list , the expectation is the name,but get list [1] an error occurred`IndexError: list index out of range`,what should I do ?

```
import sys
import os

with open("Data_aa" + ".txt","w") as file: 
    args = sys.argv[1]  
    file.writelines(args)
```

Comment: the name of the script should be sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1] should be the first argument in the call

Comment: if sys.argv[1]  unable to get input file name

Comment: Did you try to simply `print(sys.argv)` and see what you have?

Comment: print result  ['C:\\Users\\poaa\\pythonaa\\Digiaa_Parser\\dropScript.py']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is because `args` only has one element, the script name, not two. If you are trying to access the script name, use `args[0]`.